# Capitalization for Course Titles

Tags: word-usage

Capitalization Math & English, for example:

> I registered for **math-121** or **Math-121**?

Also:

> I registered for **English-101** or **english-101**?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the style found in your institution's publications, and study their style guide. Example (University of Nottingham, UK):

> Course and module titles
>
> Always capitalise course and module titles, but do not capitalise
>   subject areas or topics not used as part of a course or module title.
>
> We offer the Corporate Law module to final-year students.
>
> Some of our lecturers are experts in corporate law.

English is always capitalised. Math if it is a course or module title.

https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/communicationsmarketing/services/service-details/style-guide/capitalisation.aspx

Comment: Yes, _English_ is always capitalized – unless we happen to be talking about the **other** kind of english: _You put some nice english on that shot!_ (Even then, though, many writers prefer to use the upper-case E.)

Comment: @J.R.  Yes, but can the English explain english in plain English?  :)

Answer (score 0):

I would capitalize these because they are proper nouns: the name of a specific course.

Comment: Well, when talking about the language, _English_ should always get a capital E, whether it's the name of a course or not.